Can anyone identify this 6-pin SMD integrated circuit? (multi-charger)
This is a part of the ISDT N16 multi-charger.
The part labeled BF seems to be broken.
I think it's SOT-23-6, but I'm not sure.
It is connected in parallel with a gate of 8 FETs and is presumably a gate driver, but when I compared it to the data sheets of several gate drivers, I did not find a matching pinmap.
Any idea what part it is?

Pin 1 is connected to GND.
Pin 2 is connected to the MCU through a resistor.
Pin 3 is connected in parallel to the gate of the MOSFET (A46TF)
Pin 4 is supplied with 12 V.

The fault is that the charger does not recognize the inserted battery because there is no output on pin 3.
I would like to replace the broken part.
Any help from anyone with information would be appreciated.



CLOSE VOTER:   Please explain why. The OP provided available information. There is a good and correct answer. Question (now) has 5 upvotes and answer has 7.

It's an Onsemi BC847BPDW1 dual transistor.


(Source: lcsc.com)

You saved me~~
I didn't know it was the transistor.
Thank you so much for providing detailed information, photos, and links.
